# Center different size images horizontally and vertically in a fixed div

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of a struggle here with positioning an image inside a div.
The div is fixed to 219x197px but images are loaded with wordpress and I need to proof it so that even if the image is smaller or larger than that, it will be centered and with overflow hidden if larger and either stretched or centered if smaller (what happens when its smaller doesn't really matter).

I do not want to resize the image, I just want to show it centered and whatever fits on the div shown while the rest is hidden with overflow.

I found another question around with which I managed to center it horizontally, but I cannot do it vertically.

I tried some margin-left with percentage but it is not constant with different image sizes.
I also tried some stuff with `line-height` and `vertical-align` but nothing seems to work properly.

Does anyone know anything I could try? Thanks in advance!
Here's the HTML and CSS as it works to center horizontally:

```
<div class="img_article">
<span>
<?php get_post_image($post->ID,'large'); ?>
</span>
</div>

.img_article {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EF5589;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 219px;
    height: 197px;
    text-align: center;
}
.img_article > span {
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: -390px; /* -(width-container width)/2 */
}
.img_article > span > img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you tried with line-height and vertical-align, but it should be working.

```
.img-hold { height: 200px; line-height: 200px; text-align: center; }
.img-hold img { verticale-align: middle; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kvvTh/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't really work with the other code I have: span, display, span width and height, etc.